# how to check GIT code checkout history in GitHub

Tags: github

This question is GitHub related. Is it possible to see who checked out (*downloaded on his machine*) our public repository code and when?

Comment: GitHub maintains an audit log or user actions on a given repository.  You can [read about it here](https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization/).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not member of any organization. My question was regarding public repositories. question updated....